# diagonal matrix and invertible matrix proof

Tags: inverse

I am given the following proof question:

> Let $A \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n} $.`
>   Show that there exist invertible matrices $B$, $C$ such that $A=B+C$.

I believe it has something to do with diagonal matrix, but maybe I am wrong.
thank you for the help

Comment: Who is $C$ ?...

Comment: If $A$ is given, we should show that there exists $A$ invertible? Are you sure?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "exists $B$, $C$ invertible . . ."?  Cheers!

Comment: Corrected, thank you

Answer (score 3):

I presume you mean there exist $B$ and $C$...

Hint: let $B$ be a multiple of the identity.  Think about eigenvalues.

Comment: hi. didnt able to follow what you mean. would you mind to elaborate please? thank you!

Comment: $A = cI + (A - c I) $ is an example as long as $c \ne 0$ and $c$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Try to construct $B$ upper triangular, and $C$ lower triangular.

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't need much information about eigenvalues to solve this problem, for if $\mu \in \Bbb R$ is sufficiently large, then both $A - \mu I$ and $\mu I$ are invertible, and

$A = (A - \mu I) + \mu I; \tag 1$

it is easy to see $\mu I$ is invertible if $\mu \ne 0$; what about $A - \mu I$?  well, if

$\mu > \Vert A \Vert, \tag 2$

where $\Vert A \Vert$ is the standard operator norm of $A$ (actually, any norm on $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$ will do), then

$\Vert \mu^{-1} A \Vert = \mu^{-1} \Vert A \Vert < 1, \tag 3$

which in the usual, standard way implies the series representation of $(I - \mu^{-1}A)^{-1}$,

$(I - \mu^{-1}A)^{-1} = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty (\mu^{-1}A)^j \tag 4$

converges, since it is dominated by

$\displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \Vert \mu^{-1} A \Vert^j = \dfrac{\Vert \mu^{-1}A \Vert}{1 - \Vert \mu^{-1}A \Vert}; \tag 5$

thus

$\mu^{-1}(\mu I - A)^{-1} = (I - \mu^{-1}A)^{-1} \tag 6$

exists, as does

$(\mu I - A)^{-1} = \mu (I - \mu^{-1}A)^{-1}; \tag 7$

thus

$A - \mu I = -(\mu I - A) \tag 8$

has an inverse, and therefore (1) expresses $A$ as the sum of the two invertible matrices $A - \mu I$ and $\mu I$.

Comment: Thank you, you think there is a way involoving diagnoel matrix in a different approach?

Comment: Well, $\mu I$ *is* a diagonal matrix, as simple as they come.  So though I'm pretty sure there are other approaches involving diagonal matrices, they will likely be more complicated.  The point is the $\mu I$ "swamps" $A$ when $\mu$ is big enough. ..

Comment: My professor said he want me to this kind of approach

Comment: All I can show is what I know!  Cheers!

Comment: This is more complicated than necessary.  All you need is $\mu \ne 0$ and not an eigenvalue of $A$.  There are at most $n$ eigenvalues of $A$, so ...

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  i guess my response to your comment would be the equivocal "yes and no" . . . if one considers the material necessary to establish the machinery of eigenvalues, then I think my answer is relaitively simple, especially considering the fact that I probably said more than is necessary, i.e. presented the power series for $(I - \mu^{-1}A)^{-1}$ etc.  A similar approach using eigenvalues would have to establish the the *existence* of same, which needs the fundamental theorem of algebra:

Comment: It seems to me if one figures in the distance one must traverse from the starting gate to attain this result, my approach is relatively simple.  Anyway, thanks for the input.  By the way, I am a self-professed admirer of you work here.  You seem to have mastered the art of the short and sweet answer, unlike myself.  Hell's bells, what long comments I do post! :)